# Export MS Access 2010 table to Excel 2010

Tags: excel, export

I'm having problems with a bit of code which exports a table from MS Access 2010 in Excel 2010 format. The code runs fine in Access and the file is created. However, when I try to open the file in Excel 2010  I receive an error message as follows:

Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is not valid.

Here's the code

```
      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acExport, _
      spreadsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
      TableName:="Table1", FileName:="C:\MyDocuments\Myfile.xlsx"
```

Many thanks in advance

M

Answer (score 4):

Use `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` instead, as `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` can cause version problems (inconsistencies)...